# Selenium select options in multiselect

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, automation

I have a https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect, and I tried to select options, so as documentation says, I did this:

```
Dim selectElement As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Supplies"))
Dim selectObject = New SelectElement(selectElement)
selectObject.SelectByValue("value1")
```

But I get

> "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'Element 
> could not be scrolled into view'"

I tried to add a wait, but I still get the same message.
The HTML of multiselect is the following: [image]

Comment: This is the python command to scroll to the element `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', selectElement)`, try to implement it in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with c#, I would do something like this:

Click the button to open the drop down

then you could use

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='Supplies']/option[contains(text(), 'test1')]")).click();